# Displaying JSON with ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON data in the  format

```
[

    {
        "_1": {
            "id": 4,            
            "cost": 45.0,
            "measure": 4,
            "NoOfUnits": 677,            
            "hours": null
        },
        "_2": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Truck",
            "description": "Test"        
        }
    },
    {
        "_1": {
            "id": 1,
             "cost": 1120.0,
            "measure": 1,
            "NoOfUnits": 500,
             "hours": null
        },
        "_2": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "PC300",
            "description": null           
        }
    },
]
```

I'm not able to display the data that I have store in a $scope variable say

> $scope.result

This is my ng repeat functionality

```
<div ng-repeat="data in result">{{data.name}}{{data.description}}</div>
```

Comment: have you put ng-app directive accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

your `$scope.result` is contains `2 objects`, with in one object u have set of `object properties` like `_1,_2` , and then these `properties` are again objects like

```
"_1": {
    "id": 4,            
    "cost": 45.0,
    "measure": 4,
    "NoOfUnits": 677,            
    "hours": null
}
```

, then u have the `properties` u need to print.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in result">        // repeats objects
       <ul ng-repeat="obj in x">      // repeat object properties '_1',"_2" , these are again objects
           {{obj.name}}{{obj.description}}
       <ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

With your data structure... You cannot access name and description directly from first ng-repeat.

Even if you have nested ng-repeat you are not guaranteed with name and description. You need to flatten the object after first ng-repeat and then you can access all the properties. Assuming that _1, _2 object properties are related.

Answer (score 0):

Two loops are required---

```
<div ng-repeat="data in result">
   <div ng-repeat="obj in data">
       {{obj.cost}}{{obj.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8254/

Comment: This is not correct. In the first obj there will be no name key and in secomd obj there will be no cost key.

Comment: @ashfaq.p : check the fiddle!!

Comment: It will work because if something is not available it will not dispaly but its not the right way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.I shall edit the JSON in normal array format